# Comparing lists in Mars Rover simulation

Tags: python, list

I'm writing a program that simulates a basic mars rover.  The matrix is "mars" where the first two numbers are x and y coordinates and the third is a safety score which decides if a given coordinate is navigable (0-bad 4-good). The "rover" is able to only travel directly to the right or down (start-0,0 and end-3,3). My program is able to tell what coordinates are safe but I am struggling to find a way to compare these to find a safe path. I need to find a way to compare the output shown so that the x or y coordinate is only changed by one (to the right or down) to determine a path.

```
# This is mars
matrix = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 4], [0, 2, 1], [0, 3, 0],
          [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 0], [1, 3, 1],
          [2, 0, 0], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [2, 3, 2],
          [3, 0, 0], [3, 1, 0], [3, 2, 1], [3, 3, 1]]

# This decides if a given coordinate is safe
def is_safe(sublist):
    if sublist[2::3] == [0]:
        return False
    else:
        return True

# As of now this just stores safe coordinates in a list
def find_paths():
    for sublist in matrix:
        if is_safe(sublist):
            safepath.append(sublist)

safepath = []
find_paths()
print(safepath)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 4], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 3, 1], [2, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 1], [2, 3, 2], [3, 2, 1], [3, 3, 1]]
```

Comment: `sublist[2::3]` should be `sublist[2:3]`. But that's just one element, so why not just `if sublist[2] == 0:`?

Comment: Tip: `if something: return True; else: return False` can simply be `return something`. And if you reverse the two returns, it can be `return not something`

Comment: Your data structure doesn't seem very useful for finding paths. It would be better if you had a 2-dimensional structure where the indexes are the coordinates, instead of a list of coordinates.

Comment: Then you can find neighboring locations simply by adding and subtracting to the indexes.

Comment: Use a recursive algorithm. The base case is `[3,3]`, when you get there you're done. Find the coordinate to the right. If it's safe, recurse from it. Find the coordinate down. If it's safe, recurse from it.

Comment: I'm not sure how much more help I can be without writing it for you, but you won't learn anything that way.

Comment: @Barmar Appreciate the input, would it be feasible to use a recursive algorithm with the current data structure?

Comment: Yes, it's just harder to find the neighboring cells. You need to search the list for the cell with the incremented coordinate.

Comment: I suggest you write a function that takes `x, y` parameters and returns the sublist with those coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example per Bamar's comments:

```
m = {}
for x,y,z in matrix:
  entry = m.get(x, {})
  entry[y] = z
  m[x] = entry

m[0][0] # outputs 1; i.e. m now contains matrix in normalized form
```

Now your problem is moving around in a traditional 2d matrix as opposed to parsing a list in a weird way.